# how to include css style to modify existing placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This question is very related with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css), but after reading and trying the different jsfiddles I cannot make it work in my case.

I have an existing source base which has bootstrap 2.3.1 and LESS. At the time being I cannot modify or recompile LESS, I can only modify existing HTML and use inline styles.

Is it possible to include this:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #999;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #999;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #999;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #999;
}
```

In a simple input field with a placeholder like this:

```
<input id="some_id" placeholder="Lorem ipsum rocks da house!"/>
```

I've tried something similar to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tarR/) with some success (I'm able to change font-size only) but I've read that bootstrap with LESS has a [mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14884114/526801) for placeholder that I think is interfering with this method. Actually, if I refresh, I can see for a fraction of a second the style specified inline, but then suddenly changes to what I think is specified in that mixin.

Any ideas how to overcome this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the "!important" statement to all your rules... as shown below:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #999 !important;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #999 !important;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #999 !important;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #999 !important;
}
```

...that should force the browser to use those rules over the LESS mixins

Comment: Thank you Abimbola, and what about where to put this? Can it be placed as an inline style?

Comment: Yes, it can be...will work just the same. (Don't forget to accept this answer as the correct one! Cheers)

Comment: Hello Abimbola...Can you provide an example on how to include this inline? style=? I've tried all sort of combinations and none work

Comment: style="color:#999 !important;" is and example. if you a link to a jsFiddle, then post it in the comments, and I'll look and tell you what's blocking it, hopefully!